# Steps for fixing/rescuing data on external-storage

Tags: linux, hard-drive, data-recovery

A friend gave me his "broken" external-usb-hard drive which contains important stuff. So I plugged in the usb into my (linux-)notebook and ran `dmesg`.

The output shows, that the OS wasn't able to detect any partition or even mount the disc. It was full of error-messages all beginning with `blk_update_request: I/0 error, dev sda ...`.

My first try was to run `ddrescue -n -N -d /dev/sda test.img test.logfile`. Unfortunately the produced test.img-file was empty after ddrescue stopped running a few hours later. Using ddrescue and also `smartctl -t short /dev/sda` to let the harddrive doing a self check (which ends in a "*everything seems fine*"-like message) covers all my knoweledge of datarescue steps. So are there any other possible steps to understand the situation and do a file-rescue/disc-repair?

Comment: This is odd. My system and https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Invoking-ddrescue disagree quite significantly on the meaning of `-n`; online equates that to `--no-scrape` whereas my system equates it to `--no-split` (and my system doesn't know about `-N`). You may want to double-check that parameter set. Also tell us what *exactly* "empty" means; I assume that either `test.img` or `test.img-file` from your question was just a typo in the question. And stop trying to mount anything on a drive you intend to run ddrescue on; it can't ever help, and may hurt.